# Photoshop Selections Off A Few Pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-creative-suite, pixel

I have had this issue for quite a while, and have found no info to help me. Also, the issue doesn't always show up. What is happening is when I select something with the marquee tool, the selection doesn't start at the position I click. It's usually a few pixels off. It also does this with the ruler tool. I'll click at a point to start measuring and the ruler starts at a completely different spot. Really annoying! Anyone else have this problem and/or know a way to fix it. I'm using Photoshop CS4 btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before as well. I was able to fix it by disabling “Use Graphics Processor” under Preferences / Performance (I'm using CS6, so the names may be slightly different).

There's a little more discussion here: [Photoshop: Inaccurate selections with Radeon graphics cards on Mac OS](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/inaccurate_selections_after_installing_lion)

Of course, disabling GPU will slow things down...

It's worth noting that I'm not seeing this issue now (CS6 / 10.7.3 / Mac Pro / ATI Radeon HD 5770).

Comment: Hmm, I may try that. Don't want things to be slow though :( haha. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem when using CS4 + XP64. However, when I upgraded to Windows 7 and CS5, the problem went away (I'm probably also using newer drivers than I had back then). I guess Mac users will have to either dualboot Windows 7 and buy a Windows license for Photoshop, or file a bug report with Apple and ask them to fix the drivers.

Comment: @Lèse: I'm not seeing the issue now. When I saw it, I think I was using CS4 and a different Mac. I haven't seen it in a while, certainly not with CS6 and my current Macs.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem myself in Photoshop CS5 running Snow Leopard on a Mac Pro. No graphics setting changes have permanently kept this issue from coming back up. However, when it does, pressing `F` to cycle through screen modes clears the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be the pixels from the marquee tool (select range). Start by selecting the inner pixels. For example, if a box is 250px wide, start by selecting from the 2nd pixel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry